# Azure DevOps - User Profile - Disallow update on some fields

Tags: azure-devops

in Azure DevOps, it is possible for a user to update its profile information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsplB.png)

Is it possible to disable edition of specific fields such as "Full Name" and "Contact email"?

Our organization would like to use the info from AAD and not letting user enter some ridiculous info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but for now this is not supported. You can check this [similar post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2726#issuecomment-446756632) in Github.

I checked the related feature requests in our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), but can't find any feature request about this topic. So if you do want this feature, feel free to post a feature request (`Suggest a feature` button) in our User Voice forum.